# “the origination’s marquee U.S. event” mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, terminology, culture

> It marks the 50th anniversary for the sports organization that spotlights and supports children and adults with intellectual disabilities, and it’s the second time the former women’s champion has participated in **the origination’s marquee U.S. event**.

I saw the sentence from [this article](https://www.yahoo.com/sports/qs-charlotte-espn-body-issue-ronda-rousey-special-olympics-202919637.html). I don't understand **the origination’s marquee U.S. event**. I think it might be culture-related. Appreciate if one can help! Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a mistake and it should be "the organization's marquee US event"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on an obvious typographical error which is unlikely to be encountered by any future visitor.

Answer (score 0):

I've read it 3 times and I think it actually refers to the event hosted by the WWE at the Olympics under a major tent (marquee). I might be wrong.

Comment: A *[marquee](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Late_Show_with_Stephen_Colbert_marquee.jpg)* in American English almost always refers to a sign, and almost never refers to a tent or canopy set up for a party or exhibit (these are simply *[party tents](https://www.walmart.com/c/kp/party-tents)*). It's unlikely an American writer for an American website discussing an American athlete at an American company's event would use it otherwise.

Comment: @choster what's the *marquee US event* then?

Comment: @dan It is the event the entire article is about: the  2018 Special Olympics USA Games.